# How to get the start and end events from a table

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following records in a table

```
session_id sequence timestamp
1           1       298349
1           2       299234
1           3       234255
2           1       153523
2           2       234524
3           1       123434
```

I want to have the following results

```
session_id  start       end
1           298349      234255
2           153523      234524
3           123434      123434
```

How can I do this in pig?

Answer (score 1):

```
register 'file:$piglib/datafu-1.2.0.jar';

define FirstTupleFromBag datafu.pig.bags.FirstTupleFromBag();

input_data = load 'so.txt' using PigStorage('\t') as (session_id:int, sequence:int, time:long);

g = group input_data by session_id;

r = foreach g {
    s1 = order input_data by sequence asc;
    s2 = order input_data by sequence desc;
    generate group as session_id, FirstTupleFromBag(s1, null).time as start, FirstTupleFromBag(s2, null).time as end;
}

dump r;
```

First of all we group by session_id, then sort by sequence ascending and descending order and take the first tuple of the sorted bags respectively.

This makes use of the datafu UDF library (http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/bags/FirstTupleFromBag.html)

Comment: Awesome, this is really a very nice logic +1 .